# Unable to find Mule repo in public Git repo

Tags: mule, mule-esb, mulesoft

I am not able to access the below git public repo, is it removed? If so where we need to get the Mule-3/4 community kernel codebase. Can anyone advise?

https://github.com/mulesoft/mule

Comment: I just noticed the same thing, the repo seems to have been removed or moved somewhere else; anyone @MuleSoft would like to let us know where and what's going on?

Comment: I've created a support case (number 00224749) to request background info on this.

Comment: @RubinSimons - Thanks, pls let me know their comments as I don't have login access with Mulesoft.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I received the following reply today on case number 00224749:

```
Case #: 00224749
Outcome: Solution Suggested
Product: 
Type: Question
Severity: S4

Latest Comment:
The repository is back online at https://github.com/mulesoft/mule. 
Please accept again our apologies for any inconvenience. 

Best Regards, 
MuleSoft Support
```

And indeed, I can git pull again :-).